# replace function for javascript string with double quotes

Tags: javascript, regex

The string value

```
var a="background("text.jpg")"; //this value i got from css
```

need to replace double quotes " with || (two pipe symbol) as background(||text.jpg||)

```
a.replace(/"/g, "||")
```

But It is not working since i am having the string with already double quotes in it `background("text.jpg")` , is it possible to do the conversion.

Actually I am trying to convert vw, vh units to px from Lea Verous code ref: https://gist.github.com/LeaVerou/1347501

see my code:

```js
/**
 * StyleFix 1.0.3 & PrefixFree 1.0.7
 * @author Lea Verou
 * MIT license
 */
(function(){function k(a,b){return[].slice.call((b||document).querySelectorAll(a))}if(window.addEventListener){var e=window.StyleFix={link:function(a){try{if("stylesheet"!==a.rel||a.hasAttribute("data-noprefix"))return}catch(b){return}var c=a.href||a.getAttribute("data-href"),d=c.replace(/[^\/]+$/,""),h=(/^[a-z]{3,10}:/.exec(d)||[""])[0],l=(/^[a-z]{3,10}:\/\/[^\/]+/.exec(d)||[""])[0],g=/^([^?]*)\??/.exec(c)[1],m=a.parentNode,f=new XMLHttpRequest,n;f.onreadystatechange=function(){4===f.readyState&&
n()};n=function(){var b=f.responseText;if(b&&a.parentNode&&(!f.status||400>f.status||600<f.status)){b=e.fix(b,!0,a);if(d)var b=b.replace(/url\(\s*?((?:"|')?)(.+?)\1\s*?\)/gi,function(b,a,c){return/^([a-z]{3,10}:|#)/i.test(c)?b:/^\/\//.test(c)?'url("'+h+c+'")':/^\//.test(c)?'url("'+l+c+'")':/^\?/.test(c)?'url("'+g+c+'")':'url("'+d+c+'")'}),c=d.replace(/([\\\^\$*+[\]?{}.=!:(|)])/g,"\\$1"),b=b.replace(RegExp("\\b(behavior:\\s*?url\\('?\"?)"+c,"gi"),"$1");c=document.createElement("style");c.textContent=
b;c.media=a.media;c.disabled=a.disabled;c.setAttribute("data-href",a.getAttribute("href"));m.insertBefore(c,a);m.removeChild(a);c.media=a.media}};try{f.open("GET",c),f.send(null)}catch(p){"undefined"!=typeof XDomainRequest&&(f=new XDomainRequest,f.onerror=f.onprogress=function(){},f.onload=n,f.open("GET",c),f.send(null))}a.setAttribute("data-inprogress","")},styleElement:function(a){if(!a.hasAttribute("data-noprefix")){var b=a.disabled;a.textContent=e.fix(a.textContent,!0,a);a.disabled=b}},styleAttribute:function(a){var b=
a.getAttribute("style"),b=e.fix(b,!1,a);a.setAttribute("style",b)},process:function(){k('link[rel="stylesheet"]:not([data-inprogress])').forEach(StyleFix.link);k("style").forEach(StyleFix.styleElement);k("[style]").forEach(StyleFix.styleAttribute)},register:function(a,b){(e.fixers=e.fixers||[]).splice(void 0===b?e.fixers.length:b,0,a)},fix:function(a,b,c){for(var d=0;d<e.fixers.length;d++)a=e.fixers[d](a,b,c)||a;return a},camelCase:function(a){return a.replace(/-([a-z])/g,function(b,a){return a.toUpperCase()}).replace("-",
"")},deCamelCase:function(a){return a.replace(/[A-Z]/g,function(b){return"-"+b.toLowerCase()})}};(function(){setTimeout(function(){k('link[rel="stylesheet"]').forEach(StyleFix.link)},10);document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",StyleFix.process,!1)})()}})();
(function(k){function e(b,c,d,h,l){b=a[b];b.length&&(b=RegExp(c+"("+b.join("|")+")"+d,"gi"),l=l.replace(b,h));return l}if(window.StyleFix&&window.getComputedStyle){var a=window.PrefixFree={prefixCSS:function(b,c,d){var h=a.prefix;-1<a.functions.indexOf("linear-gradient")&&(b=b.replace(/(\s|:|,)(repeating-)?linear-gradient\(\s*(-?\d*\.?\d*)deg/ig,function(b,a,c,d){return a+(c||"")+"linear-gradient("+(90-d)+"deg"}));b=e("functions","(\\s|:|,)","\\s*\\(","$1"+h+"$2(",b);b=e("keywords","(\\s|:)","(\\s|;|\\}|$)",
"$1"+h+"$2$3",b);b=e("properties","(^|\\{|\\s|;)","\\s*:","$1"+h+"$2:",b);if(a.properties.length){var l=RegExp("\\b("+a.properties.join("|")+")(?!:)","gi");b=e("valueProperties","\\b",":(.+?);",function(a){return a.replace(l,h+"$1")},b)}c&&(b=e("selectors","","\\b",a.prefixSelector,b),b=e("atrules","@","\\b","@"+h+"$1",b));b=b.replace(RegExp("-"+h,"g"),"-");return b=b.replace(/-\*-(?=[a-z]+)/gi,a.prefix)},property:function(b){return(0<=a.properties.indexOf(b)?a.prefix:"")+b},value:function(b,c){b=
e("functions","(^|\\s|,)","\\s*\\(","$1"+a.prefix+"$2(",b);b=e("keywords","(^|\\s)","(\\s|$)","$1"+a.prefix+"$2$3",b);0<=a.valueProperties.indexOf(c)&&(b=e("properties","(^|\\s|,)","($|\\s|,)","$1"+a.prefix+"$2$3",b));return b},prefixSelector:function(b){return b.replace(/^:{1,2}/,function(b){return b+a.prefix})},prefixProperty:function(b,c){var d=a.prefix+b;return c?StyleFix.camelCase(d):d}};(function(){var b={},c=[],d=getComputedStyle(document.documentElement,null),h=document.createElement("div").style,
l=function(a){if("-"===a.charAt(0)){c.push(a);a=a.split("-");var d=a[1];for(b[d]=++b[d]||1;3<a.length;)a.pop(),d=a.join("-"),StyleFix.camelCase(d)in h&&-1===c.indexOf(d)&&c.push(d)}};if(0<d.length)for(var g=0;g<d.length;g++)l(d[g]);else for(var e in d)l(StyleFix.deCamelCase(e));var g=0,f,k;for(k in b)d=b[k],g<d&&(f=k,g=d);a.prefix="-"+f+"-";a.Prefix=StyleFix.camelCase(a.prefix);a.properties=[];for(g=0;g<c.length;g++)e=c[g],0===e.indexOf(a.prefix)&&(f=e.slice(a.prefix.length),StyleFix.camelCase(f)in
h||a.properties.push(f));!("Ms"!=a.Prefix||"transform"in h||"MsTransform"in h)&&"msTransform"in h&&a.properties.push("transform","transform-origin");a.properties.sort()})();(function(){function b(a,b){h[b]="";h[b]=a;return!!h[b]}var c={"linear-gradient":{property:"backgroundImage",params:"red, teal"},calc:{property:"width",params:"1px + 5%"},element:{property:"backgroundImage",params:"#foo"},"cross-fade":{property:"backgroundImage",params:"url(a.png), url(b.png), 50%"}};c["repeating-linear-gradient"]=
c["repeating-radial-gradient"]=c["radial-gradient"]=c["linear-gradient"];var d={initial:"color","zoom-in":"cursor","zoom-out":"cursor",box:"display",flexbox:"display","inline-flexbox":"display",flex:"display","inline-flex":"display",grid:"display","inline-grid":"display","max-content":"width","min-content":"width","fit-content":"width","fill-available":"width"};a.functions=[];a.keywords=[];var h=document.createElement("div").style,e;for(e in c){var g=c[e],k=g.property,g=e+"("+g.params+")";!b(g,k)&&
b(a.prefix+g,k)&&a.functions.push(e)}for(var f in d)k=d[f],!b(f,k)&&b(a.prefix+f,k)&&a.keywords.push(f)})();(function(){function b(a){e.textContent=a+"{}";return!!e.sheet.cssRules.length}var c={":read-only":null,":read-write":null,":any-link":null,"::selection":null},d={keyframes:"name",viewport:null,document:'regexp(".")'};a.selectors=[];a.atrules=[];var e=k.appendChild(document.createElement("style")),l;for(l in c){var g=l+(c[l]?"("+c[l]+")":"");!b(g)&&b(a.prefixSelector(g))&&a.selectors.push(l)}for(var m in d)g=
m+" "+(d[m]||""),!b("@"+g)&&b("@"+a.prefix+g)&&a.atrules.push(m);k.removeChild(e)})();a.valueProperties=["transition","transition-property"];k.className+=" "+a.prefix;StyleFix.register(a.prefixCSS)}})(document.documentElement);



/**
 * Polyfill for the vw, vh, vm units
 * Requires StyleFix from -prefix-free http://leaverou.github.com/prefixfree/
 * @author Lea Verou
 */
var tt;
(function() {

if(!window.StyleFix) {
 console.log("out" );
 return;
}

// Feature test
var dummy = document.createElement('_').style,
 units = ['vw', 'vh', 'vm'].filter(function(unit) {
  dummy.width = '';
  dummy.width = '10' + unit;
  return !dummy.width;

 });

if(!units.length) {
 console.log("out2");
 return;
}

StyleFix.register(function(css) {
 var w = innerWidth, h = innerHeight, m = Math.min(w,h);
 console.log(w);
 
 console.log("################## ");
 css =css.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"");
 css =css.replace(/["']/g, "zzz")
 console.log(css);
 return css.replace(RegExp('\\b(\\d+(\.\\d+)?)(' + units.join('|') + ')\\b', 'gi'), function($0, num, d, unit) {
  console.log("hiiii");
  switch (unit) {
   case 'vw':console.log($0);console.log(d);console.log(num);console.log(unit);
    console.log((num * w / 100) + 'px');
    console.log((num * w / 100) + 'px');
    return (num * w / 100) + 'px';
   case 'vh':console.log($0);console.log(d);console.log(num);console.log(unit);
    console.log((num * w / 100) + 'px');
    return num * h / 100 + 'px';
   case 'vm':console.log($0);console.log(d);console.log(num);console.log(unit);
    return num * m / 100 + 'px';
  }
 });
});

})();
```

```css
/*test4.css*/

#testtarget1{
 
 font-size:3vw;
}
#testtarget2{
 
 font-size:5vw;
}
#testtarget3{
 background:url("test.jpg");
 font-size:7vw;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='test4.css'/>
</head>

<body>
  <div id='testtarget1'>Some text</div>
  <div id='testtarget2'>Some text</div>
  <div id='testtarget3'>Some text</div>
  
  <script src="prefixfree.js"></script>
  <script src="vunits.js"></script>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: How are you getting the string? Add relevant code. Using double quote inside double quoted string is Syntax error, regex can't help in this situation.

Comment: The double quotes around `background("text.jpg")` are not **real** double quotes present as characters in the string; they are merely a syntactical device to indicate a string literal. Your regexp should work fine, assuming you actually have `var a = "background(\"text.jpg\")";`. What is not working?

Answer (score -1):

Here is what you are looking for:

```
var a="background(\"text.jpg\")";
a = a.replace(/"/g, "||");
console.log(a);
```

Outputs:

> `"background(||text.jpg||)"`

[Here is a JSBin](https://jsbin.com/gexixo/edit?html,js,console,output).

This is because `replace` returns a new string.

Comment: Don't need `m` flag. How is this different from OP code.

Comment: @Tushar maybe I misunderstood what he was asking, but this seems to do exactly what the question asked for? Replace double quote with double pipes.

Comment: `m` means multiline, not multiple times. `g` means multiple times (=all matches). `m` is unnecessary in a one-line string.

Comment: @Juhana my bad, my regex isn't the best. Thanks.